# Lotus Domino: After changing TYPE of a field, Full Text Search won't work for this field

Tags: lotus-domino

*My problem*:
I can't Full text search a view with the syntax [field_name] = text_value. Not in lotus Script nor in the "search the view" in the client.
*Additional information*:
When searching/More/By field / selecting my field, I get a combo box with "is equal to", "is greater than" ... meaning that for the FT index my field is (was in fact) NUMBER.
But The field has been change to text years ago, existing data converted to text, full text index re created, OSD changed (hum I should check this). => But the old type (number) is still written somewhere in Iris/Lotus systable (sort of systable).

***My question***: How to update the FT engine, or to tell him that the type is text now?

thanks in advance!

I already had the same problem many years but I can't find the solution with google or here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the notes database you have a section called the UNK table. This keeps a reference of every field in the database and field type. you can see this in Notespeek.

It only keeps a reference of the first field it finds. So if you have multiple fields with the same name but different types the FTI will get confused when you search on the field.

More details and solution to resolve is in this tech note.

https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21261002

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, it solved my problem (at least on my test db, I will schedule a compact on week-end on the prod DB)<br><br>
WARNING: It seems that to rebuild the UNK Table, we need copy style: load -c dbname.nsf.<br>
i.e. Compact without parameter doesn't help, nor load compact -B...
<br><br>
again Thanks !