# View Search ( Notes error: Query is not understandable)

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I am trying to create a Xpage view search in application, for the below  query alone I am getting an error  **"Notes error: Query is not understandablecode"**

**Code:**
var strQuery="Field cc_number=\"DADM20121012174051\"";
return strQuery;

For other Queries I have created, the search is working fine.
can any one tell me why this error is  coming.I read in web the size limit of search query is 1024 bytes.Link:http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO68462. I think the above Query is not exeeds the 1024bytes..

Comment: I think Simon and Panu provided answers already but I want to add a  link which might be interesting for you (from Notes help): http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp

Comment: Can you Please re-post the link. because its opening the index page only..

Comment: Try that - I hope it loads in English... http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.notes85.help.doc%2Fsch_refine_query_r.html

Answer (score 1):

That does not give me an error in client but in my understanding the syntax is:

```
FIELD cc_number CONTAINS DADM20121012174051
```

OR

```
[cc_number]=DADM20121012174051
```

Give those a try.

Comment: I tried above code still results the same. as Simon said I change the datatype of the duplicate field name and followed the procedure(delete index,compact,create new index)..still getting the same error..

Comment: One thing to try is to make sure the index files are deleted at OS level. Often they are not.

Answer (score 0):

With most full text search issues, I recommend to first test in the Notes client to see what results you get back.

In this case you want to try.

```
Field cc_number="DADM20121012174051"
```

Doe's that work? If it doesn't then it could be related to the UNK table, see the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151448/lotus-domino-after-changing-type-of-a-field-full-text-search-wont-work-for-th).

After that put on the following debug to your notes.ini on the server.

```
CONSOLE_LOG_ENABLED=1
Debug_FTV_Search=1
DEBUG_THREADID=1
```

When you do a search now, it will generate debug for that search, and save it in a console.log file under the IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder. Add the debug output to your question above and I can comment on it (remove anything confidential that may show up).

Answer (score 0):

@Simons way is the right one, in the case of a longer query, you might replace the
Field cc_number
be the square brackets, so that it becomes
[cc_number]
and completes to a query like this
[cc_number]="DADM20121012174051"
One more thing that might lead to the error you see: is there any document in the database or view that stores a numeric instead of a string value in the cc_number item? If that's the case the FTSearch might get confused by your directive to search for a string and finding a candidate that holds a number value and then cries for help by throwing an error. I'm suggesting only to iron out if that's possibly the case here...