# Domino Designer query: numeric operation

Tags: syntax, lotus-domino

When submitting a query via `NotesDatabase.FTSearch` I get the error message:

```
Notes Error: Query is not understandable 
(FIELD Form="Contact" AND ( FIELD CUSTOMER_ID <> 1)) (262)
```

The same query with an equals performs normal (same with `<=` and `>=`):
(`FIELD Form="Contact" AND ( FIELD CUSTOMER_ID = 1)`)
Therefore I think there is an error on the "not equal" operator.

[The documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_FTSEARCHRANGE_METHOD_DB_JAVA.html) explains various operators on numeric values except the "not equals" operation. 
Even worse it states, that

> You cannot put NOT after the math symbols =, <, >, <=, or >=; and before a date or number

So whats the proper way to do it? `<>` and `!=` didn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601395/view-search-notes-error-query-is-not-understandable/14601659#14601659

Comment: Also it would be something like...  AND NOT ( FIELD_CUSTOMER_ID = 1 ) ... I think, :/ need to test that.

Comment: Thank you Simon for your help. `AND NOT ( FIELD CUSTOMER_ID = 1 )` did work!

Answer (score 3):

This works at least for text fields:

```
![CUSTOMER_ID]=1
```

Giive it a try, I'm not sure about numeric. If it does not work you can do this:

```
[CUSTOMER_ID]>1 OR [CUSTOMER_ID]<1
```

Simon's suggestion might work also (without the first underscore).

Comment: @Markus OK good. Then I believe `![CUSTOMER_ID]=1` works also, it's just a shorter syntax and that's why I prefer it.