# Lotus Domino database FTSearch method and brackets

Tags: lotus-domino

I need to search with FTSearch something like this - `MS004790(419411/10)`. But it thorws `NotesException: Notes error: Query is not understandable (MS004790(419411/10))`

So maybe there is some trick to search strings like that or maybe I need to parse it somehow?

Tnx for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Wrap your search in quotes.

Full Text search has two modes. Web Search and Notes Search. In your notes preferences you can set this.

[image: preferences]

Web search is just like a text search. Notes search attempts to parse the search term.

However the client can fall back to Notes search terms if it sees the first characters are capitals (or capital reserved keywords like "FIELD"). So to prevent it from parsing you need to wrap it in quotes.

For example

(LotusScript)

```
searchString = |"MS004790(419411/10)"|
```

(Java)

```
searchString = "\"MS004790(419411/10)\""
```

If it is still failing after that, manually try the search in the FT search bar. Once you have that working the code should work the same way.

If it is still failing at that point it may be related to the UNK table. If so see the following:

[Lotus Domino: After changing TYPE of a field, Full Text Search won't work for this field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151448/lotus-domino-after-changing-type-of-a-field-full-text-search-wont-work-for-th/9151751#9151751)

Comment: Tnx a lot! You help me again!